# C++: Cannot open files with stringstream operation

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, stringstream, istringstream

I am editing an existing C++ code such that it opens multiple files using stringsteam. I have a loop with an integer going from 1 to 7, and there are 7 files that I need to open. The files are named PMAP1.txt ... PMAP7.txt. I am trying to open it this way:

```
            ifstream precipfile;
            int j = 0;
            stringstream ss;
            string FileName;

            for(j=1;j<6;j++){

                ss <<"PMap" << j <<".txt" << endl;
                FileName = ss.str();
                precipfile.open(FileName.c_str(),ios::in);

                if( !precipfile.good() )
                   ReportFatalError( "Unable to find or open precipfile" );
            }
```

This does not work for some reason.It returns "Unable to find or open precipfile". But if I 
open one file just by using one filename directly it works.Like:

```
                    string FileName = ( "PMap.txt" ); 
                    precipfile.open(FileName.c_str());
```

This works.Please help!

Comment: Print `ss.str()` each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your loop you are not resetting the `stringstream` object

```
ss <<"PMap" << j <<".txt" << endl;
```

thus you keep appending stuff to the stringstream without removing the previous stuff added. Replace the above line in your loop with the following 2 lines to correctly clear the `stringstream` at each iteration.

```
ss.str("");
ss <<"PMap" << j <<".txt" << endl;
```

This is why the code only works once - the first time the stream is cleared, but subsequent iterations it contains all the characters you have added at previous iterations.

Comment: do not know yet..there seems to be another problem somewhere else so I can not run the prog yet..Will post as soon as I can run it.Thanks.

Comment: @mathematician1975..Thanks,that did work..The problem was also that the ifstream was not being reset every time.So I put that declaration and stringstream declaration inside the loop and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is too small - change it to `for (j = 1; j <= 7; j++)`.